# Get two divs lined up with one another centred on page

Tags: html, css

How would I get the following two divs centred on the same page?

**HTML**

```
    <div class="setRegularFont centerText buttonText"><a href="#">BUTTON 1</a></div>
    <div class="setRegularFont centerText buttonText"><a href="#">BUTTON 2</a></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.buttonText {
    width: 10%;
    border: 1px solid #818181;
    color: #818181;
    margin-top: 2em;
    padding: 1em;
    display:inline-block;
}
.buttonText a,a:visited,a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #818181;
}
.buttonText a:hover, .buttonText:hover a {
    color: #1f1f1f;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.buttonText:hover {
    border: 1px solid #1f1f1f;
}
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/p6mtfqv5/).

Comment: Have you tried wrapping them in another element? then using margin: 0 auto; on the parent element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two solutions. You can either wrap those two `<div>`'s with another `<div>` and then set the `text-align` property to `center` of that `<div>` using CSS, like this:

```css
#centered {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.buttonText {
  width: 10%;
  border: 1px solid #818181;
  color: #818181;
  margin-top: 2em;
  padding: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
}
.buttonText a,
a:visited,
a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #818181;
}
.buttonText a:hover,
.buttonText:hover a {
  color: #1f1f1f;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.buttonText:hover {
  border: 1px solid #1f1f1f;
}
```

```html
<div id="centered">
  <div class="setRegularFont centerText buttonText"><a href="#">BUTTON 1</a>
  </div>
  <div class="setRegularFont centerText buttonText"><a href="#">BUTTON 2</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Second solution is to simply set the `text-align` property of your `<body>` to `center` using CSS, like this:

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  }

.buttonText {
  width: 10%;
  border: 1px solid #818181;
  color: #818181;
  margin-top: 2em;
  padding: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
}
.buttonText a,
a:visited,
a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #818181;
}
.buttonText a:hover,
.buttonText:hover a {
  color: #1f1f1f;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.buttonText:hover {
  border: 1px solid #1f1f1f;
}
```

```html
<div class="setRegularFont centerText buttonText"><a href="#">BUTTON 1</a>
</div>
<div class="setRegularFont centerText buttonText"><a href="#">BUTTON 2</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap them in a `div` and then centre everything in that div. Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/p6mtfqv5/4/

**CSS**

```
.center {
    width:100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="center"><div class="setRegularFont centerText buttonText"><a href="#">LAST MAN STANDING</a></div><div class="setRegularFont centerText buttonText"><a href="#">OF PURE GOLD</a></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[What I did here](http://jsfiddle.net/p6mtfqv5/1/) was I made one div right: 50% and the other with left: 50%. They then stick together in the center. (Note that they both have to have `{position:absolute;}`)

Answer (score 0):

Just place the `<div>` tag into the `<center>` tag:

```
<center>
 <div class="setRegularFont centerText buttonText"><a href="#">BUTTON 1</a></div>
 <div class="setRegularFont centerText buttonText"><a href="#">BUTTON 2</a></div>
</center>
```